# How to cancel upload file to server and delete file (between upload not finished) when we use ajax post requests to upload file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

How to cancel upload file to server and delete file (between upload not finished) when we use ajax post requests to upload file ?

this is my ajax upload

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'example.php',
    dataType: 'text',
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: form_data,                         
    type: 'post',
    success: function(php_script_response){
    }
});
```

example.php

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "dir/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

Comment: you can use php method exit() or die() and for delete file it will not save on temp if php code exit.

Answer (score 0):

PHP provides a way to track your upload progress, read more about it here - http://php.net/manual/en/session.upload-progress.php

The upload progress will be available in the $_SESSION when an upload is in progress. You can get the key name for your upload using this,

```
$key =  ini_get("session.upload_progress.name");
print_r($_SESSION[$key]);
```

Now to cancel your upload, simply call the $_SESSION with the key and set cancel_upload to TRUE.

```
$_SESSION[$key]["cancel_upload"] = true;
```

This will only abort the in-progress uploads and not the completed ones.